# Javascript - Clicking Span with Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug

From I understand this is supposed to be quite simple, yet I'm getting an error while doing it. I have website a button with different span's within the button, the spans change using Jquery once they're clicked apon. Using Firebug, I'm trying to see that my click method works on the first span text, yet for some reason I'm getting the following error. What am I doing wrong? (Note, latest Jquery is being used on the page)

**HTML:**

```
<button id="signup_forms_submit" class="chrome big on_dark signup_forms_submit touchy blue">
        <span class="account_btn">Start</span>
        <span class="birthday_btn">Next</span>
        <span class="captcha_btn"><span><b>Almost</b> <b>Done!</b></span></span>
        <span class="login_btn">Log in</span>
    </button>
```

**Jquery Command:**

```
$('.account_btn').click();
```

**Firebug Console Log:**

```
TypeError: $(...) is null

$('.account_btn').click();
```

Comment: Is the code before the HTML? Are you running it after dom.ready?

Comment: Yes, and yes. Button code is inbetween other HTML, and running after dom.ready.

Comment: Can you reproduce this on jsFiddle.net?

Comment: And what is supposed to happen when you trigger that click ?

Comment: `$(...)` is never null with jQuery. You have some other issue. Did something else hijack the dollar sign?

Comment: i just noticed that in chrome, the $ sign is indeed hijacked even on a blank page. it is a shortcut for some selectors

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('span .account_btn').click();
```

Comment: It is getting null because you aren't getting any output when you click the button.  I just copy and pasted it into JSFiddle and the button doesn't do anything.  That is why you are getting null.  I also copied it in Google Chrome, and I am getting a < error on your first line.  Also the class name you are giving your button "chrome big on_dark signup_forms_submit touchy blue  Needs to be with underscores.  You can't have spaces for anything in Javascript.

Comment: jQuery $ does not return null so it has nothing to do with the selector! If the selector returns nothing it is a jQuery object with a length of zero.

Comment: I am not talking about jQuery, I am talking about when you click there is nothing. Perhaps make the click 'do something' then it won't be null.

Answer (score 0):

Never seen "subbuttons" inside of a button. First try to create single buttons, maybe spans but not inside this button tag.
Is this html generated using js? maybe you should use

```
$(document).on('click','.account_btn', function(){...});
```

then.

Comment: Seems like the OP is changing the text of the button by hiding spans.

Comment: All I did was take the quotes off from around `'document'` - figured I would go ahead and change it for you rather than creating a comment and having you do something so minuscule =P. No worries

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have a compatibility problem there.

Try:

```
$J = jQuery.noConflict();
$J(function() {
    $J('.account_btn').click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your console, type:

```
jQuery
```

what does that give you? because it looks like you didn't load jQUery at all. Try opening a new tab (an empty tab) and entering that into console, see what you'll get :-)

```
$('.span').click()
TypeError: Cannot call method 'click' of null
```

Answer (score 0):

As your span is inside the button the initial click event will trigger button's click event and not span's specific action.

If you want different events for each of the span inside your button you should enclose them on a div, not a button and bind an event:

```
$(function(){  
    $('span.account_btn').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        // Do something
    });
});
```

Also if you write the following you ll see that the span with the class "account_btn" is not null.

```
$(function(){
    console.log($('span.account_btn'));
});
```